# SQL: Select items not bought by customer on daily basis

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has daily purchase of a customer. I am trying to get the list of all items that the customer did not purchase on daily basis.

More explanation: Below is the table

```
+------------+---------+------------+
| dt         | product | product_id |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 2019-01-01 | Milk    |          1 |
| 2019-01-02 | Bread   |          2 |
| 2019-01-03 | Butter  |          3 |
| 2019-01-04 | Beer    |          4 |
| 2019-01-05 | Salt    |          5 |
| 2019-01-06 | Sugar   |          6 |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

I am trying to get a report of Not purchased items based on the whole list.

```
+------------+------------------------------+
| dt         | product_not_purchased        | 
+------------+------------------------------+
| 2019-01-01 | Bread,Butter,Beer,Salt,Sugar |
| 2019-01-02 | Milk,Butter,Beer,Salt,Sugar  |
| 2019-01-03 | Milk,Bread,Beer,Salt,Sugar   |
+------------+------------------------------+
```

For the sake of simplicity the data here is for just one customer and only one item will be purchased by the customer. But the dates are not static, the dates could keep growing with irregular frequency.

Sample query for one day:

```
select dt, product, product_id from
trans  where product_id not in (select distinct product_id
from trans where dt not in ( '2019-01-01'))
where dt = '2019-01-01';
```

I am trying to extend it for each day. I tried using CTE and partitions but it did not work. 
The other solution I though was to create a temp table and use minus clause.
How should I go about solving this problem? or Is temp table the best solution?

SQL Queries to create table and insert values. I am using MySQL:

```
create table trans (dt date, product varchar(10), product_id int);


insert into trans values ('2019-01-01','Milk',1);
insert into trans values ('2019-01-02','Bread',2);
insert into trans values ('2019-01-03','Butter',3);
insert into trans values ('2019-01-04','Beer',4);
insert into trans values ('2019-01-05','Salt',5);
insert into trans values ('2019-01-06','Sugar',6);
```

Comment: Do you have a products table so you can compare the products purchased to it? If not what is the basis? The distinct products purchased so far?

Comment: Is there a lookup table that contains all available products? Also, does `trans` table contain the items purchased per customer? If yes, then the sample 'not purchased items' list provided is not consistent.

Comment: there is no lookup table. Just one table with products.

Comment: its just a trans table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the `trans` table:

```
select dt, group_concat(product order by product) product_not_purchased from (
  select distinct t.dt, tt.product from trans t
  inner join trans tt
  on tt.dt <> t.dt
) t
group by dt
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/NUmeDWXXiGGwcmLwVfpRc/4)

Comment: the above query is returning an empty set. Not sure of I need to add any conditions to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate all products on all days.  Then filter out the ones that have been purchased and aggregate the rest:

```
select d.dt, group_concat(p.product)
from (select distinct dt from t) d cross join
     (select distinct product from t) p left join
     t
     on t.dt = d.dt and t.product = p.product
where t.product is null
group by d.dte;
```